# Ingesting data from REST api to Kafka

Tags: rest, apache-kafka

I have many REST API to pull the data from different data sources, now i want to publish these rest response to different kafka topics. Also i want to make sure that duplicate data is not getting produced.
Is there any tools available to do this kind of operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in general a Kafka processing pipeline should be able to handle messages that are sent multiple times. [Exactly once delivery of Kafka messages](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) is a feature that's only been around since mid 2017 (giving that I'm writing this Jan 2018), and Kafka 0.11, so in general unless you're super bleedy edge in your Kafka installation your pipeline should be able to handle multiple deliveries of the same message.

That's of course your pipeline. Now you have a problem where you have a data source that may deliver the message to you multiple times, to your HTTP -> Kafka microservice.

Theoretically you should design your pipeline to be idempotent: that multiple applications of the same change message should only affect the data once. This is, of course, easier said than done. But if you manage this then "problem solved": just send duplicate messages through and whatever it doesn't matter. This is probably the best thing to drive for, regardless of whatever once only delivery CAP Theorem bending magic [KIP-98](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging) does. (And if you don't get why this super magic well here's a homework topic :) )

Let's say your input data is posts about users. If your posted data includes some kind of `updated_at` date you could create a transaction log Kafka topic. Set the key to be the user ID and the values to be all the (say) `updated_at` fields applied to that user. When you're processing a HTTP Post look up the user in a local KTable for that topic, examine if your post has already been recorded. If it's already recorded then don't produce the change into Kafka.

Even without the `updated_at` field you could save the user document in the KTable. If Kafka is a stream of transaction log data (the database inside out) then KTables are the streams right side out: a database again. If the current value in the KTable (the accumulation of all applied changes) matches the object you were given in your post, then you've already applied the changes.